# What is the word for a person who destroys momentum?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a person who destroys the momentum of something being planned, or of a currently running plan. Like it could be something they say or do, or just their presence. I know the word buzzkill exists but I don't it fits to describe a person who says they can't make it to an event because of work or something, and this causes all planning to stop.(maybe it does? If so I guess I'm looking for a synonym for buzzkill?(which in that case I don't know why I posted this, instead of using google))

Comment: **Stick-in-the-mud**: *one who is slow, old-fashioned, or unprogressive*. (M-W)

Comment: I'm thinking more like every one is saying they're available Saturday, and have picked a time and an activity, then one person is like "oh sorry guys, I'm celebrating my Dad's birthday". So all the planning goes down the drain, and nothing happens that Saturday

Comment: Dampener, party-pooper, killjoy, downer, wet blanket, cold fish, wet fish (and presumably cold blanket).
From Urban Dictionary:  
harshmellow, killday, potong stim.

From Urban Thesaurus:
bk, buzzkillington, buzzkill, broiler (because BK - Buzzkill - also
 stands for Burger King, who sell a BK Broiler sandwich), bk broiler,
 broygus (adjective), clungepotato, dead bunny, fun killer,  human
 paraquat (because Paraquat can be used to kill marijuana), 
 rumplepuss, swagvamp, whopper bk and (even worse) windows 7 whopper bk,
zurg (Buzz Lightyear's antagonist)

Comment: From both a physics and social perspective, a ***drag*** destroys momentum.  Don’t be such a drag.

Comment: lol Jim I like that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple terms for that are:

**party pooper**

1. a person who refuses to join in the fun of a party;
2. broadly : one who refuses to go along with everyone else

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/party%20pooper

You might say, "Oh, come on.  Don't be a party pooper.  Come to the party.  It's not gonna happen if you don't."

Literally, it's someone who poops on a party or poo-poos a party, destroying it.  I mean, it's use is metaphoric, but that's what it literally means. That seems more apropos to your example.

*and*

**killjoy**

1. one who spoils the fun of others

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/killjoy

You might just as well say, "Oh, come on.  Don't be a killjoy.  You're ruining everyone's fun."

*If neither of those work, I think if you type either of them into a thesaurus, you'll the word you're looking for.*